# PostgreSQL upper function on the ascii 152 character ("ÿ")

Tags: sql, postgresql, unicode

On a Windows 7 platform, with PostgreSQL version 9.3.9, using `PgAdmin` as a client, the result of select upper on a column containing e.g. `"ÿÿÿ"`, `returns` `null`. If three values are stored, e.g.,

```
"ada"
"john"
"mole" 
"ÿÿÿ"
```

they all come back in upper case, except the row containing `"ÿÿÿ"`; this row
gives nothing back, `null`...

The `database` encoding scheme is `UTF8 / UNICODE.` The setting "client_encoding" has the same value, `UNICODE`.

Is this a setting issue in the `database`, an operating system issue, or a bug
in the database? Are there some recommended workarounds?

The result of:

```
select thecol, upper(thecol), upper(thecol) is null, convert_to(thecol, 'UTF8'), current_setting('server_encoding') from thetable where ...
```

is:

```
"Apps";"APPS";f;"Apps";"UTF8"
"All";"ALL";f;"All";"UTF8"
"Test";"TEST";f;"Test";"UTF8"
"ÿÿÿ";"";f;"\303\277\303\277\303\277";"UTF8"
```

The `lc_` parts of pg_settings are:

```
"lc_collate";"Swedish_Sweden.1252";"Shows the collation order locale."
"lc_ctype";"Swedish_Sweden.1252";"Shows the character classification and case conversion locale."
"lc_messages";"Swedish_Sweden.1252";"Sets the language in which messages are displayed."
"lc_monetary";"Swedish_Sweden.1252";"Sets the locale for formatting monetary amounts."
"lc_numeric";"Swedish_Sweden.1252";"Sets the locale for formatting numbers."
```

The output of `select * from pg_database` is:

```
"template1";10;6;"Swedish_Sweden.1252";"Swedish_Sweden.1252";t;t;-1;12130;668;1‌​;1663;"{=c/postgres,postgres=CTc/postgres}" 
"template0";10;6;"Swedish_Sweden.1252";"Swedish_Sweden.1252";t;f;-1;12130;668;1‌​;1663;"{=c/postgres,postgres=CTc/postgres}"
"postgres";10;6;"Swedish_Sweden.1252";"Swedish_Sweden.1252";f;t;-1;12130;668;1;‌​1663;""
```

The actual create database statement, for the 9.4.4 version, is:

```
CREATE DATABASE postgres
  WITH OWNER = postgres
       ENCODING = 'UTF8'
       TABLESPACE = pg_default
       LC_COLLATE = 'Swedish_Sweden.1252'
       LC_CTYPE = 'Swedish_Sweden.1252'
       CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;
```

Comment: "ASCII" and "Unicode" are not the same. I get Unicode value 255 (0xFF) for ÿ and 376 (0x178) for Ÿ. See also http://unicode-table.com/en/#00FF

Comment: Column data type? (char/varchar or nchar/nvarchar?) Collation?

Comment: Column type is "character varying" (varchar), lc_collate=Swedish Sweden.1252

Comment: If I run select lower on 376 (0x178) ("ŸŸŸ") I get ÿÿÿ back. But null/nothing if I do it the other way around, i.e., select upper on 255 (0xFF) ("ÿÿÿ")

Comment: Please also show output of `select thecol, upper(thecol), upper(thecol) is null, convert_to(thecol, 'UTF8'), current_setting('server_encoding') from thetable where ...` for the row in question. Create a one-column one-row table and insert a row if you're just using literals. Then **edit the question** to add the results.

Comment: I'm using the built in SQL editor in pgAdmin. The query is: select upper("Name") from "Streams"

The result (unformatted) from the query select thecol, upper(thecol), upper(thecol) is null, 
convert_to(thecol, 'UTF8'), current_setting('server_encoding') from thetable where ...

is:

"Apps";"APPS";f;"Apps";"UTF8"

"All";"ALL";f;"All";"UTF8"

"Test";"TEST";f;"Test";"UTF8"

"ÿÿÿ";"";f;"\303\277\303\277\303\277";"UTF8"

Comment: The result from show all yields the following result for all lc types:

`"lc_collate";"Swedish_Sweden.1252";"Shows the collation order locale."`

`"lc_ctype";"Swedish_Sweden.1252";"Shows the character classification and case conversion locale."`

`"lc_messages";"Swedish_Sweden.1252";"Sets the language in which messages are displayed."`

`"lc_monetary";"Swedish_Sweden.1252";"Sets the locale for formatting monetary amounts."`

`"lc_numeric";"Swedish_Sweden.1252";"Sets the locale for formatting numbers."`

Comment: Your database is in a bad state. Have you ever done a direct `update` of `pg_database`?

Comment: @CraigRinger, ANSI SQL defines nvarchar - no idea if MS SQL Server has it or not... Doesn't Postgresql support that data type???

Comment: @CraigRinger, sorry for causing confusion, the ANSI SQL name's NCHAR VARYING/NATIONAL CHAR VARYING/NATIONAL CHARACTER VARYING. Nvarchar is just a popular nick-name.

Comment: Deleted no-longer-needed comments.

Comment: @Pr0t0c0l78 I'm tired of reformatting data you leave in comments. I have asked you to *edit the quesiton* to add new information many times. I am done, sorry, I don't want to keep on having to reformat your data so I can read it. I'm deleting my answer and moving on. You should **Edit the question** to add new information. If you do not understand what that is, say so, don't ignore it. (Tip: there's an "edit" link under your question.) Other readers: refer to deleted answer before proceeding.

Comment: I didn't do that intentionally, I was answering using comments instead of editing the question. Sorry

Comment: @Pr0t0c0l78 Yeah, but you kept ignoring it. It's a pain to keep editing it in so I can read it properly. Anyway, the point I made stands: your database is mangled, and either you did it by updating pg_database, something else run on the system did so, or you've found a really bad bug. In the latter case I'd want to see that you could reproduce it from a clean install because right now this looks like a direct update of `pg_database` resulting in a text encoding that doesn't match the collations. As I said before: dump, drop, re-load.

Comment: Once again, sorry for the inconvenience. I could reproduce it by a fresh install. Tried different settings for lc_collate and lc_ctype. The first fresh install used swedish (default in my system), the second english. When I choose 'C' as lc_collate and lc_ctype, it works. But that would have other implications, such as sorting

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the `upper` function uses the `LC_CTYPE` setting of your database. The uppercase of LATIN SMALL LETTER Y WITH DIAERESIS (U+00FF) is LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Y WITH DIAERESIS' (U+0178) which isn't part of the Windows 1252 code page.

If you convert the string to a Unicode format first, the `upper` function might work as expected:

```
SELECT upper(convert_to(thecol, 'UTF8')) ...
```

You should probably use a different value for `LC_CTYPE` and `LC_COLLATE`. On Linux, you'd use `sv_SE.UTF-8`.

Nevertheless, I'd consider this a bug in Postgres. It would be better to leave `ÿ` as is if the upper case version can't be represented in the target character set.